# Django celery beat not running multiple clocked task at same time. Is there any other way out?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I want to dynamically add tasks to run at a particular time (clocked task). I am using django celery beat. The problem I am facing is that the celery only executes one task and ignores the rest.

I have tried the following code and searched in library that the django-celery-beat disables the schedule once it has executed the clocked task. This might be the reason for other/next task not running.

What am I doing wrong? and

What can be the alternative way to schedule multiple tasks to run at same time?

```py
clocked, _ = ClockedSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
    clocked_time=next_run_time
)

PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    clocked=clocked,
    name=guid1,
    one_off=True,
    task="schedulerapp.jobscheduler.runEvent",
    args=json.dumps([guid1])
)

PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    clocked=clocked,
    name=guid2,
    one_off=True,
    task="schedulerapp.jobscheduler.runEvent",
    args=json.dumps([guid2])
)
```

Comment: I have a similar with triggered task and Django 3. Celery only takes one task and runs it on model save event event though multiple are scheduled. That is new.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule

schedule = IntervalSchedule.objects.create(every=10, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS)
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, name=guid1, task='schedulerapp.jobscheduler.runEvent', args=json.dumps([guid1]))
```

Comment: This will run the task every 10 seconds. I need to run the task at a perticular time.

Are you suggesting to calculate the time difference between now and execution time in seconds and use that as interval with one_off=True in the PeriodicTask ?

Comment: @AyushNanda Yes calculate the diff.